# How to load a ML model in the memory using gunicorn and flask?

Tags: python, flask, caching

I have a flask API deployed using gunicorn. I want to load the model in cache such that it is always available to all the gunicorn workers.
I tried using flask caching but I'm not able to use it since I'm using flask blueprint and facing circular dependency problems.
Any help is really appreciated!
This is my current folder structure -
(app is created in the outer init file and i need the models in actual_code.py)

```
folder
    __init__.py
    app.py
    app
        __init__.py
        code_folder
            v1
                route.py
                controller
                    actual_code.py
```